# Is it a good way to prevent ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, synchronization

The another question is about **synchronized**. I have also a run() in class Note,because i want to output each element in notes every 5 minutes. But i get always exception:java.util.ConcurrentModificationException,if i try to make more meetings in main. so i applay synchronized to the list notes which may be added a new meeting when i iterate over notes.My run method like this:

**Is it correct way hier on list notes to synchronized to prevent ConcurrentModificationException ?**(In my program it works.I get never this exception now)

A Meeting class and Note class may likes this:

```
public class Meeting{

    public Meeting(Note note_1,Note note_2){

                 note_1.addElement(this);

                 note_2.addElement(this);}

                 //another method hier 

                  }

public class Note implements Runnable{

    public final List<Meeting> notes = new ArrayList<Meeting>();

    public void addElement(Meeting n){

               entries.add(n);
              }

   @Override

   public void run(){
             while(true) {
             for(Meeting n : notes){

                 System.out.println(n.toString);}

                 }

             try{ Thread.sleep(10);}

             }

           }
          }
```

I get always exception error about **exception:java.util.ConcurrentModificationException**  if i try to make more Meeting in main ,So i changes a littel in class Note,likes this :

```
  private  static final List<Entry> entries = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Entry>());
```

and in run()

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        synchronized(notes){
            for(Entry n : entries){
                 //do something
                 }
            }
            try {   
                Thread.sleep(10);  
         } catch (InterruptedException e ) {
            } 
     }
   }
```

}

Comment: While the exception was what brought you here, I should also point out that your logic is not ideal, since [you shouldn't publish a reference to `this` during construction](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618.html) if you want to use multiple threads, as it can break invariants that must "always" hold.  Also, indenting your code properly and consistently will help readability a surprising amount.

Comment: Thanks Andrzej and Sorry that my code is not properly posted.Multiplethreads doesnt lead to ConcurrentModificationException in my program. It occurs when i iterate over the list in class Note and maybe a new meeting-object wants to add itself to the list

Answer (score 4):

From the javadoc

Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will thow this exception.

THis means do not change your collection in a loop and iterate over it at the same time even in the same thread.

Comment: +1, this is exactly it.  One way around this issue is to take a *copy* of the collection in question, then iterate over the copy (so that elements can be added to the original without issue).  But usually it's a sign that the logical flow isn't as clear as it could be, so it pays to think about *why* you're mutating during iteration and how else you might achieve your goals.

Answer (score 0):

Read to what @Navi had written.

In a nutshell - NEVER remove/add elements of a collection in for each loop.

I once had that kind of problem and I decided to use http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/
There are some map/filter functions there (if I recall that methods were in Collections2 library).

If you are not willing to make the things right, you can always use the old-school iterator technique.

Comment: You can remove elements from a list (while iterating) if you are iterating with the Iterator interface and you use the Iterator's remove() method. Adding elements is not supported by the Iterator interface.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) before when I encountered this sort of problem.

This makes a complete copy of the underlying array for each write, so it's not very efficient, but I've found it very useful for specific circumstances (e.g. a class which manages specialised event notification to some other classes)

> This array never changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so interference is impossible and the iterator is guaranteed not to throw ConcurrentModificationException